# Start Process using c#

Tags: c#, process, windows-installer, installshield

i have setup which i need to install using my wpf application. I am not able to pass params to setup.exe file.I am  able to install that setup using .bat file by this command:-

```
.\setup.exe /v"MYINSTALLERTYPE=Client"
```

Then how i can pass params by using c# here is my c# code:

```
 String path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo(path + "\\SetupFiles\\setup.exe","MYINSTALLERTYPE=Client");
        Process proc = new Process();
        p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        proc.StartInfo = p;
        p.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
```

Please help me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it maybe because you missed /v flag? The second line of your listing should look like:

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo(path + "\\SetupFiles\\setup.exe", "/v\"GURUINSTALERTYPE=Client\"");
```

You have to escape the needed quotes as shown, using the \ character.